# Failed to parse a schema xsd

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xsd-validation, xml-validation

Error! 
Issue with parsing this Xsd file while converting to JAXB classes.

If I remove the `xs:simpleType` right after `xOperatorId` it works
What is the issue?

***s4s-elt-must-match.1: The content of 'sequence' must match (annotation?, (element | group | choice | sequence | any)*)***

```
<xs:complexType name="inputSegmantData">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element nillable="true" name="rstClass" type="tns:flag"/>
            <xs:element nillable="true" name="rstType">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:length value="2"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>

            <xs:element nillable="true" name="rstLowSerialNo" type="tns:checkNum"/>
            <xs:element nillable="true" name="rstHighSerialNo" type="tns:checkNum"/>
            <xs:element nillable="true" name="rstLowAmount" type="tns:amount"/>
            <xs:element nillable="true" name="rstHighAmount" type="tns:amount"/>

            <xs:element nillable="true" name="rstDatePlaced" type="tns:date"/>
            <xs:element nillable="true" name="rstDateToExpire" type="tns:date" />

            <xs:element nillable="true" type="tns:date" name="xOperatorId" />
                <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                            <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:element nillable="true" name="xProjectName">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                        <xs:maxLength value="20"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element nillable="true" type="tns:date" name="xChannelId" />
            <xs:element nillable="true" name="segDelimeter" default="\u07" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The particle `<xs:element nillable="true" type="tns:date" name="xOperatorId" />` should *contain* the following `xs:simpleType` element. At present, despite the indentation, the two elements are at the same level.

Comment: Oh you're right! Simple type is not tied to any element! Thanks!